# Proper date time format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I want to display the date in this format: 21st Aug,2012 07:30 PM. I have done it using strftime like this:

```
<%= @project.planned_start_date.strftime("%d %B %Y") if @project.planned_start_date-%>
```

It is displaying like this:
02 August 2012
Can someone help me out how to get the above mentioned format of date and time ?

Comment: Why vote down anyone? the question is clear and the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to format your time value using the following strftime options?:

```
<%= @project.planned_start_date.strftime("%d %b, %Y %I:%M %p") unless @project.planned_start_date.blank? %>
```

**EDIT:** This is what you need then

```
<%= ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(@project.planned_start_date.strftime("%d").to_i) + @project.planned_start_date.strftime(" %b, %Y %I:%M %p") unless @project.planned_start_date.blank? %>
```

**OUTPUT:** "23rd Aug, 2012 09:19 AM"

Comment: It is working. Can you please tell me how to use ordinalize in this. Actually I tried it but it is giving me some error.I have print like 21st Aug,2012 07:30 PM

Comment: Yes check my answer above, I edited to include ordinalize. I'll appreciate some points, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot your code is working absolutely fine in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [strftime method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime), this has all the possible conversion characters and what they represent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have already tried gone through it but I am not getting how to get the above format.

Comment: I don't see how you expect "%d %B %Y" to give what you're asking for. You don't have anything to represent the time, and there's no comma separating the month and year.

Comment: I think there is some jquery plugin for this so that the time will also be selected. Can you please tell me which plugin is there.

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow isn't a hand holding service. If you're not going to help yourself, you can't expect people to help you.

Comment: Just to add a little bit to this answer, [ActiveSupport::Inflector#ordinalize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-ordinalize) can help with the day of month formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
 <%= @project.planned_start_date.strftime("%d %b, %Y %I:%M %p") if @project.planned_start_date.present? -%>
```

output:
   21 Aug,2012 07:30 PM

Comment: For future references: this isn't the correct answer, it's missing the ordinalize. The correct ones are Brian's and mine. See below

Answer (score 1):

```
>> t = Time.now
=> Tue Aug 21 08:59:54 -0400 2012
>> t.strftime("#{t.day.ordinalize} %B, %Y %I:%M %p")
=> 21st August, 2012 08:59 AM
```

Comment: This option I tried on console and it is working fine. Not I will try it in my application. Thanks for your help.